# For loop in gilab-ci exits when inner command produces non-zero exit code

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to launch mypy code analyze inside my gitlab-ci. I do it with following code:

```
mypy:
  only:
  - master
  script:
  - for config_path in $(find * -regex '.*__init__.py' -mindepth 2); do mypy $config_path; exit_code=$?; done
  allow_failure: true
```

Unfortunately CI stops after executing mypy on first element from list found by *find* command. Command *mypy* returns RC=2.

I put extraction of exit code into variable because of warning: *If any of the script commands return an exit code different from zero, the job will fail and further commands will not be executed. This behavior can be avoided by storing the exit code in a variable* mentioned here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#script

How can I achieve launching whole for loop despite of non-zero exit codes inside its body?

Comment: try `do mypy $config_path || true; done`

Comment: @Grumbunks: Thanks, your solution worked. You can post it as an answer to let me mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
do mypy $config_path || true; done
```

`|| true` will force a return code of 0 no matter what return code `mypy $config_path` has.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if gitlab-ci supports <() but in bash this would be

```
while read -r -d '' config_path; do mypy "$config_path"; exit_code=$?; done < <(find . -mindepth 2 -name '*__init__.py' -print0)
```

The error was likely due to -mindepth 2 coming after the -regex flag, however -name or -iname are probably better for this

Comment: Thanks for reply but unfortunately it didn't work. It stopped processing after first Pyhon file in which mypy returned non-zero RC while there are hundred of files still to check:

`$ while read -r -d '' config_path; do mypy "$config_path"; exit_code=$?; done < <(find . -mindepth 2 -name '*__init__.py' -print0)`
`test_path_1 is not a valid Python package name`
`ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Comment: This looks to be mypy specific. Try adding an empty `__init__.py` file in the test_path_1 to see if it fixes itself: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1645

Comment: The case is that the commands (your and mine) works properly on my local OS (mypy checks all files found in loop). They only don't work inside gitlab-ci as they should (only first found file is being checked).

Comment: That sounds like environment variable issues. I'd need to see your full config to know exactly what, but if you can try adding `PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:."` above the mypy script it will add the base directory to the path. This config looks correct: https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-a-python-application/

Answer (score 0):

I would just put the script inside of text file, add it to git, and just call it from `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Something like:

```
//run_mypy.sh
for config_path in $(find * -regex '.*__init__.py' -mindepth 2); do mypy $config_path; exit_code=$?; done

//.gitlab-ci.yml
mypy:
  only:
   - master
  script:
   - run_mypy.sh
  allow_failure: true
```

I have tried and struggled too many times to get complex scripts to run directly from the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. In my case it was windows batch files and powershell scripts, but they all suffer from the same problem: You have a yaml file that supports a certain format and that uses certain special characters, and inside of this you try to express a completely different format.

It is also much easier to control an exit code from a separate script then to try to figure out exactly how GitLab handles exit codes. Again, this might mostly be a problem for powershell scripts, but I would still suggest everybody to store your complex scripts outside of `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

I avoided the exit on the non-zero exit code by executing the following command in a sub-shell:

```
bash -c "set +e; for i in {1..30}; do (INSERT YOUR COMMAND HERE) && exit 0; sleep 1; done; exit 1"
```